# Wordwrap in PHP not functioning as expected

Tags: php, string

I have a LONG (720 character) string from a old mainframe table.  There are a TON of white spaces in it due to them using white space as a method of laying out text on the green screen.

Im trying to simulate that greenscreen look by using wordwrap in PHP (code below). I have tried using the call from the field directly in the code (instead of using $instructions).

I have tried converting that result into htmlentities and then nl2br'ing the result.

I have tried converting the white space to non break spaces.

I have tried replacing special characters to other things (just as a test)

I have even tried changing the number of characters to wrap at to 4, in which case all hell breaks loose and it only seems to cut things at white spaces anyway no matter how many characters are in the group of characters before or after a white space.

However, in the text of that string there is a segment within that string:

```
"1: B-140(GR) ON 140VHF F1 W/"A ZONE (#) GENERAL ALARM" T & L2: REPEAT STEP 1."
```

that SHOULD break between the L and 2 (General alarm T & L  2. etc).  Even with the cut boolean set to true, it refuses to cut L2: into two lines.  (even moving the amount of characters to 61 or even 63)  the string will not cut that "L2:" segment apart. It will either only cut before the L at the white space, or after the colon at the white space.

```
CODE
$instructions = (wordwrap($instructions,60, "<br />\n", true));
```

What am I missing? (looks for hidden cameras)

Comment: It will either break before L2 or after it as L2 is considered as a word. And since you have set it to true it will break at word when it meets 60 characters. It only break words when they are too big AFAIK,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation for wordwrap](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php): 
"If the cut is set to TRUE, the string is always wrapped at **or before** the specified width." In other words, the function just won't cut it for this particular application.

Another approach would be to use str_split, which generates an array of elements cut precisely at 60 characters:

```
$instructions = '1: B-140(GR) ON 140VHF F1 W/"A ZONE (#) GENERAL ALARM" T & L2: REPEAT STEP 1.';
$instructions_array = str_split($instructions, 60);

foreach ($instructions_array as $line) {
    echo $line."<br />\n";
}
```

Comment: Absolutely Brilliant!  Works great!  Although the documentation would lead me to believe that it would have cut the word in two (as in their Looooooooong example).

Comment: Yeah, the example in the docs is not ideal. Glad this helped!